# Payment Module in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am building a website for a aid organisation.
They want a donation module on their page.
I am trying to implement this but don't seem to get this to work.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
<div class="rnw-widget-container"></div>
<script src="https://tamaro.raisenow.com/XXX/latest/widget.js"></script> 
<script>
    window.rnw.tamaro.runWidget('.rnw-widget-container', {language: 'en'})
</script>
```

(from https://support.raisenow.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001586658-Integrate-the-Widget-into-your-Page)

Obviously I am using the API token that I received instead of XXX.

```
import React from "react"
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet"
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

const SpendenPage = () => (
    <Layout>
    <Helmet>
    <script src="https://tamaro.raisenow.com/xxx/latest/widget.js"></script>
      <script>window.rnw.tamaro.runWidget('.dds-widget-container', {language: 'de'});</script>
        </Helmet>
    <div className="dds-widget-container"></div>

    </Layout>
)

export default SpendenPage
```

> gives me this error Syntax error:
> /home/hanna/Code/brnhrz-cms/src/pages/jetzt-spenden.js: Unexpected
> token, expected "}" (9:73)

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render an expression or method invocation like `window.rnw.tamaro.runWidget('.dds-widget-container', {language: 'de'});` ins JSX you need to wrap it in curly braces.

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx) for more details.

Basically just change the following from:

```
<script>window.rnw.tamaro.runWidget('.dds-widget-container', {language: 'de'});</script>
```

to:

```
<script>{window.rnw.tamaro.runWidget('.dds-widget-container', {language: 'de'})}</script>
```

And you should at least no longer have the syntax error.

Comment: Hi, thank you !!  I am not getting the syntax error any longer, but instead this one :

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tamaro')
    at <anonymous>:1:13
    at eval (Helmet.js:512)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at updateTags (Helmet.js:511)
    at commitTagChanges (Helmet.js:387)
    at eval (Helmet.js:354)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the content of the script between backticks (``` `` ```) along with curly braces (`{}`):

```
<Helmet>
  <script src="https://tamaro.raisenow.com/xxx/latest/widget.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' async defer>
    {` window.rnw.tamaro.runWidget('.dds-widget-container', {language: 'de'}) `}
  </script>
</Helmet>
```

Be aware that [`window` and other global object limitations when using Gatsby with SSR](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/) (**S**erver-**S**ide **R**endering), it may break the compilation during the `gatsby build`. If it breaks, you may need to add the following condition before using `window`:

```
typeof window !== "undefined"
```

You can check for an example in this CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9qmrwxqzq

Related topics:

- [Adding script tag to Gatsby using helmet throws syntax errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63494846/adding-script-tag-to-gatsby-using-helmet-throws-syntax-errors)
- [Is there a way adding Freshworks chat widget to a website built on Gatsby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241194/is-there-a-way-adding-freshworks-chat-widget-to-a-website-built-on-gatsby)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Fixed it and I am not getting a syntax error any longer but a runtime error. I think that was what you where referencing. See attached error:
`Unhandled Runtime Error
One unhandled runtime error found in your files. See the list below to fix it:

Unknown Runtime Error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tamaro')

<anonymous>:

No codeFrame could be generated`

Breaking during compilation is probably what is happening. I can see the module I am trying to implement only sometimes. I was taking a look but didn't see the condition in your sandbox though.

Comment: More detailed log from console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tamaro')
    at <anonymous>:1:13
    at eval (Helmet.js:512)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at updateTags (Helmet.js:511)
    at commitTagChanges (Helmet.js:387)
    at eval (Helmet.js:354)
`

I really don't know what to make of it. I am still learning. Thank you again for your input on this so far.

Comment: The problem is that you are using `tamaro` object (because of the `runWidget`) and maybe at the time you are requesting it the previous script (the one that loads the library) may not be loaded yet. Try adding an `async`/`defer` loading